# How to revert next build and export command in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Is there any way to revert the files after your press build command in Next.js?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to revert when you use `next build`. What it does is creating a `.next` folder which contains all the built files.

If you don't want the files just delete the `.next` folder in your project root directory.